# How to provoke a compile-time error if a specific overload of a function is called?

Tags: c++, constructor-overloading, string-view

According to https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view/basic_string_view, `std::basic_string_view` class has 7 overloaded ctors. I only care about 2 of them since right now I don't use the rest of them in my code.

These are the instances that I care about:

```
constexpr basic_string_view( const CharT* s, size_type count );
constexpr basic_string_view( const CharT* s );
```

I need to prevent the code from calling the second one (due to it potentially causing a buffer overflow for non-null terminated buffers).

I have something like below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <array>

void func( const std::string_view str )
{
    if ( str.empty( ) )
    {
        return;
    }

    std::stringstream ss;

    if ( str.back( ) == '\0' )
    {
        ss << str.data( );
    }
    else
    {
        ss << std::string{ str };
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::array<char, 20> buffer { };
    std::cin.getline( buffer.data( ), 20 );

    const std::string_view sv { buffer.data( ), buffer.size( ) };

    func( sv ); // should be allowed
    func( { buffer.data( ), buffer.size( ) } ); // should be allowed
    func( buffer.data( ) ); // should NOT be allowed!
}
```

What is the correct way of doing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add another overload taking `const char*` and mark it as [delete](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function#Deleted_functions) (since C++11).

```
void func( const char* str ) = delete;
```

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/UPtOq8B6QZNDTALd)